Looking for an example of a GETKEY-FUNC function to implement org-table-sort-lines correctly
When I use org-table-sort-lines on this column it doesn't work correctly.
| tsk_description  |
| tskg_description |
| tskg_id          |
| tskg_name        |
| tskg_project_id  |
| tsk_name         |
| tsk_task_id      |
| tsk_tskg_id      |

After asking on Reddit org-table-sort-lines is not sorting some lines correctly : orgmode I got a response that I have to use a custom GETKEY-FUNC parameter to org-table-sort-lines to implement a sort that is not affected by the underscore as that is an org-mode markup character.
I have tried the solution at Sorting an org-table numerically, ignoring commas (org-table-sort-lines) - Emacs Stack Exchange by using (replace-regexp-in-string "tsk_" "tska" str) but with no success.
What I missing? I take it that the comparing function must be the default sort-subr.

There are two relevant functions here: the function that is used to extract a key from the table and the function that is used to compare keys. When you choose alphabetic sorting, the function that extracts keys is org-sort-remove-invisible which does indeed strip emphasis characters from the string (do C-h f org-sort-remove-invisible for details)1.
What you want is to have the key be identical to the text of the column: no transformations.
For that, you have to specify the func sorting type and when it asks you what key extraction function you want to use, say identity. You can leave the function for comparing keys empty, thereby choosing the default sort_subr predicate.

EDIT: when I do M-x org-table-sort-lines on the following table, specify column 1 as the sort column, choose f for the sorting type, type identity for the key extraction function and leave the predicate empty:
| tsk_description  |
| tskg_description |
| tskg_id          |
| tskg_name        |
| tskg_project_id  |
| tsk_name         |
| tsk_task_id      |
| tsk_tskg_id      |

I get this table:
| tsk_description  |
| tsk_name         |
| tsk_task_id      |
| tsk_tskg_id      |
| tskg_description |
| tskg_id          |
| tskg_name        |
| tskg_project_id  |

Looks correct to me.

Footnote:
[1] The situation here is more complicated than this naive description might indicate and I don't fully understand it, but the underscores are certainly not stripped.

I just tried it and it didn't work, using the identity function.

Try again - you are either doing something wrong or you are expecting a different result: _ sorts before g by default. Check the edited answer for what I get.

The most recent change to org-table-sort-lines was on May 5, 2024, commit 4131926984fa8240a526a6cf3d8ef76c1df1dbbe. That was included in Org 9.6.30 and later. What version of Org do you have?

This one is version Org mode version 9.5.5 (release_9.5.5 @ /usr/local/share/emacs/28.2/lisp/org/)

OK - I'll try it on that version then. EDIT: I tried it on 9.5.5 and it works the same way as I show in the answer. If you don't get the same result, something is fishy in your setup. Try with emacs -Q

BTW, can you edit your qet your question and show what table you do get? That's always better than saying "it didn't work".

I tried it another profile and it works in that one although it is the same version, so I suspect there is something wonky in the profile I'm using. The result is the very same one in the question.
I will try out those in the other related questions which also had the same issue.
